# Horizontal align submenu Wordpress WPEX Adapt theme

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment, submenu

I want to align my submenu horizontally instead of vertically. I'm using Wordpress 4.4, I'm using the WPEX Adapt theme (free theme). My website is: http://goo.gl/XIlRWF

I hope somebody can help!

p.s. I put the following code in my child theme style.css but it doesn't work yet:

```
.sf-menu li {
    float: left !important;
}
.sf-menu ul {
    width: 600px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was that the theme uses Superfish, I changed theme and could edit the css easy. This did the trick:

```
.sf-menu li {
    float: left !important;
}
.sf-menu ul {
    width: 400px;
}
```